# Adding a list within a list in python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and trying to understand the syntax.

in my example, i would like to have a result of: table = [[1,2,3], [2,4,6], [3,6,9]]
but somehow i get and empty list. I am not sure where to fix it.

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = [1, 2, 3]
li = []
table = []
for x in row:
    for n in col:
        li.append(x*n)
    table.append(li)
    li.clear()

print(table)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `li.clear()`?

Comment: `table.append(li[:])` - if you clear the same list that you're appending to the table, obviously you'll end up with `[]`. Append a copy instead

Comment: @yatu, he was doing it to get the output described, as opposed to:  `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,2,4,6],[1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9]]`

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, lists are pointers. This means that when you append a list to another list, it is not creating a new list, it is using the same list.
So whenever you do `li.clear`, it gets rid of the internal list elements...

you're gonna want this instead...

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = [1, 2, 3]
table = []
for x in row:
    li = []
    for n in col:
        li.append(x*n)
    table.append(li)

print(table)
```

Create a new list each time, so it's a separate object in memory for each `append` operation

Comment: Upvote for providing not only a solution but also an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

using your own code:

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = [1, 2, 3]
table = []
for x in row:
    li = []
    for n in col:
        li.append(x*n)
    table.append(li)

print(table)
```

you will then get:

[image: output]

Comment: Answer is correct but it would be more helpful if you explain *why* it works.

Answer (score 0):

```py
row = [1,2,3]
col = [1,2,3]
table = []

for x in row:
  li = []
  for n in col:
    li.append(x*n)
  table.append(li)
```

The difference is making the `li = []` variable inside the first level of your for loop. This essentially "clears" it out each time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into what is mutabe and immutable in python

Let me explain in brief what happens in your code

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = [1, 2, 3]
li = []
table = []
for x in row:
    for n in col:
        li.append(x*n)
    table.append(li) # everything is good until here
    li.clear() # but here you are sayning that li is empty so it also goes and changes table.append(li) to table.append(li.clear()), because li is a list and lists are mutable objects. 
# what you can do is create another new object (which happens to be named li: li=[] so the table.append(li) will not change to table.append([])
```

change your code to

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = [1, 2, 3]
li = []
table = []
for x in row:
    for n in col:
        li.append(x*n)
    table.append(li)
    li = []

print(table)
```

Comment: my thought process was really just the flow of the code, i didnt know clear would still affect the upper part. I guess my understanding about clear is not enough.